# How to retain spacing between bars for two different bar charts in Chart.js 2

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I have two horizontal bar charts using Chart.js that are using the same options object, but different amounts of data. Is there a way to make the bottom ("places") chart look like the top ("colors") in terms of margin between the bars?

[image: Two horizontal bar charts with different spacing]

My options object looks like the following, I am stumped:

```
      options={{
        elements: {
          rectangle: {
            borderSkipped: 'left',
          },
        },
        onClick: this.chartLink,
        animation: false,
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: false,
            },
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              display: false,
            },
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            tabIndex: 0,
            maxBarThickness: 100,
            categoryPercentage: 1.0,
            barPercentage: 1.0,
            barThickness: 20,
            gridLines: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: false,
            },
            ticks: {
              fontColor: 'black',
              fontStyle: 'normal',
              maxTicksLimit: 5,
              paddingLeft: 20,
              mirror: true,
            },
          }],
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scale the height of the second chart to match the ratio of the # of elements in the two charts.

Chart.js requires a container around the canvas to allow dynamic resizing so you'll need to add that to the html also.

I needed to set `maintainAspectRatio: false` for this to work

```js
// scale second chart based on ratio of data to the first
var fiddleFactor = 1.05; // determined by guesswork. Basic ratio is slightly off.
var ratio = data2.labels.length * fiddleFactor / data1.labels.length;

var container1Height = parseInt(document.getElementById("container1").style.height);

// update height of second chart
document.getElementById("container2").style.height = container1Height * ratio + 'px';
```

```html
<div id="container1" class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:300px;">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="container2" class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:300px;">
  <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/LZMAtY0MOQpLunyGhpzH?p=preview

Comment: This was the missing piece. Thank you. I will award the bounty as soon as it allows me to do so.